# For loop with np.where and multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array of values called flux_limit:

```
flux_limit = np.array([0.08333333,0.11785113,0.14433757...])
```

that has 99 values in it. I am trying to use those values as a condition using np.where() for a search through a catalog I have read into python. I want to basically get the number of values from the catalog for each flux limit that satisfy these two conditions:

```
index=[[]]
for i in flux_limit:
     index = np.where((catalog['snu_arr'][6]*1000 > i) & (catalog['zgal'] > 6.))
```

I expect that because this is giving the indices of the values that satisfy these two conditions, I will end up with a list of lists with each internal list corresponding to a flux_limit value. I understand how to do this with only one value, I just run into an error when throwing this in a for loop:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3636586,) (2,).
```

I've googled what this error means, but the answers are usually specific to the user's problem and I am not savvy enough to diagnose my problem.

Edit:

```
catalog['snu_arr'][6] = [  4.81194684e-09   5.13640614e-08   5.48405854e-09 ...,   2.95787549e-06  3.43822015e-09   2.17239404e-09] 
catalog['zgal'] = [  0.01027171   0.01691939   0.01614619 ...,  10.18688393  10.21286678 10.20675182]
```

This catalog is huge, 3636586 values, which is where the first number in the error message comes from.

Edit 2:
So both catalog['zgal'] and catalog['snu_arr'][6] are of the same length.

```
print(catalog['zgal'].shape, catalog['snu_arr'][6].shape)
>>>((3636586L,), (3636586L,))
```

Here is what I do for only one value in flux_limit:

```
index = np.where((catalog['snu_arr'][6]*1000 > .083) & (catalog['zgal'] > 6.))
print(index)
```

which gives this as an output

```
(array([3615964, 3616643, 3616732, 3617188, 3618296, 3618976, 3619040,
   3619205, 3619429, 3620039, 3620142, 3620185, 3620487, 3620810,
   3621045, 3621375, 3621396, 3621828, 3622030, 3622326, 3622713,
   3622999, 3623137, 3623202, 3624357, 3624919, 3625077, 3626185,
   3626558, 3626666, 3627142, 3627279, 3627660, 3628004, 3628558,
   3629997, 3630053, 3630128, 3630801, 3631271, 3631567, 3632210,
   3632269, 3632285, 3632589, 3633107, 3633816, 3634833, 3635190,
   3635307, 3635608, 3635711, 3635767, 3636159, 3636227], dtype=int64),)
```

To my understanding, these are the indices of the values that satisfy the two conditions above. For some reason, it gives the output as a list of lists, so I find the number of values using len().

```
print(len(index[0]))
>> 55
```

Comment: What do `catalog['snu_arr'][6]` and `catalog['zgal']` look like?

Comment: @Scimonster I added that in my edit.

Comment: `catalog['snu_arr'][6]` and ` catalog['zgal']` seem to be of different shapes/sizes. So, those two comparisons would result in different shaped boolean arrays and as such their `AND-ing`  doesn't make sense. Still, just to confirm, could you get their shapes with `catalog['snu_arr'][6].shape` and `catalog['zgal'].shape`? Additionally, could you add a minimal representative sample case and explain the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar Both are the same shape/length. I gave an example of what I do/want with only one value of flux_limit. I want the length of the index array for each value of flux_limit.

Comment: Hmm, I guess just to add few diagnostics there, you could assign those comparisons to arrays : `mask1 = catalog['snu_arr'][6]*1000 > i` ; `mask2 = catalog['zgal'] > 6.`. Then, print their shapes and finally use : `index = np.where(mask1 & mask2)`. Do all these inside that loop and then run the code. When you see that error, trace back the shapes of mask1 and mask2 and see if they still match up. If they do, then really there's something going on.

Comment: @Divakar Weird. Now it doesn't give me an error, but gives me the same output as if I had only put in the first value of flux_limit. It didn't iterate over all values...